# What do you call a long "chain" of a repeated character?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do you call a very long line of the same character, which happens when the button is being continuously pressed? It may be accidentally or on purpose (for a visual effect). I've tried googling `long chain of characters` or `stack key` but neither is correct.

[image: Bird with an open beak in front of a background filled with "A"s]

Comment: With my computer science background I'd call it a long **string** of characters -- but otherwise I know of no common term for this.  You do your best to describe what you mean and hope the listener understands.

Comment: I think that would make a valid answer: long repeated string of characters

Comment: It's *an* answer, but not *the* answer.  My official answer is that there is no official answer  :)

Comment: This can be done, not just for "visual effect," but to convey the way a word might be drawn out when spoken. When I read “a looooooong chain of characters,” I read that quite differently than “a long chain of characters,” at least audibly in my mind.

Comment: I might be tempted to call it an Onomatopoeia, but it doesn't *really* fit. I would be surprised if this style doesn't have a name.

Comment: Does it have a name in your native language?

Comment: @J.R. Can you give an example for being drawn out when spoken? I don't understand this. What do you hear at "looooooong chain" in your mind?

Comment: @JamesK no, it's not

Comment: @Ooker - Sure. “And now, ladies and gentlemen, [heeeeeeeeere’s Johnny](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZKmsA8bzao).” (You’ll hear that about 30 seconds into the video clip.) For that matter, at the very beginning, you can also hear, “Froooom Hollywood!”

Comment: @J.R. Ah I see. What I mean is the audible effect that can only be conveyed through visual effect :D

Comment: @Ooker - No, it’s audio – not video. A sound file would have worked just fine. It just so happens that the easiest place to find audio bites on the Internet is at a video site. :-)

Comment: @J.R. No, what I mean is visual effect is the only thing you can convey in text. My last comment may be confusing, what I mean is that you and I are on a same page

Comment: lengthening a vowel sound for visual or aural effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lengthening a vowel sound for aural or visual effect.

The explanation given in this blog is the right idea but poorly expressed because it is the vowel sounds only that make the word longer when spoken: [I Can Lengthen My Words and So Can Youuuuuuu](https://jezebel.com/5987133/i-can-lengthen-my-words-and-so-can-youuuuuuu)

Visually, it would be: repeating a single character repeatedly for visual effect.

The two ideas are  not in the same space.

Comment: Also in the link: "elongated". What is the second idea you mention?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenated

I do this aaaaaalllll the time, usually with awesoooommmmeee! My friends now even say 'awesomie' verbally which is a bit wierd!

I'm borrowing 'concatenated' which is used in computing where strings of characters are glued together for various reasons into data strings.

Concatenate means 'to link things together in a chain or series'.

I'm saying that the repeated letters are joined together, like a chain.

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=concatenate&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

Answer (score -1):

> loooooooooong chaiiiin of character ...

I second Andrew's statement: I guess there is no word for it. By the way, in German there is no word for it too.

<sub>*Note: I am neither a native speaker nor an expert - I am just trying to help.*</sub>